# django formset validating even though there are way too many

Tags: python, django

I have a formset that I wanted to have a somewhat arbitrary amount of forms with. Here are the formset classes.

```
class ChartDatasetForm(forms.Form):
    """Giving the form a dataset, meant to be repeated with formsets"""

    data_label = forms.CharField(label="Data Label", max_length=100)
    dataset = forms.CharField(label="Data", max_length=1000)


ChartDatasetFormset = formset_factory(
    ChartDatasetForm, min_num=1, validate_min=True, max_num=1000, validate_max=True)
```

and then I have some tests like this...

```
class FormTests(TestCase):
    """Testing that the forms work as expected"""

    def setUp(self):
        """Setting up data for forms"""

        self.dataset = {
            'form-TOTAL_FORMS': 2,
            'form-INITIAL_FORMS': 0,
            'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': 1,
            'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': 1000,
            'form-0-data_label': '',
            'form-0-dataset': '',
            'form-1-data_label': '',
            'form-1-dataset': '',
        }

    def test_chart_dataset_validates_with_2_sets(self):
        """Testing that the form validates when there are two datasets"""
        for n in range(2):
            self.dataset['form-%s-data_label' % n] = 'the labels'
            self.dataset['form-%s-dataset' % n] = '1, 2'
        form = ChartDatasetFormset(self.dataset)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())

    def test_chart_dataset_validates_with_3000_sets(self):
        """Running up to the max amount of forms to see if it validates"""
        for n in range(3000):
            self.dataset['form-%s-data_label' % n] = 'the labels'
            self.dataset['form-%s-dataset' % n] = '1, 2'
        form = ChartDatasetFormset(self.dataset)
        form.clean()
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

as you can see, the chart is validating when there are 3000 forms even though I set the `max_num` at 1000. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change

```
'form-TOTAL_FORMS': 2
```

to >1000, I think the test test against this attribute instead of the actual data

```
'form-TOTAL_FORMS': 1003,


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bobby/Documents/code/python/hello/try/tests.py", line 38, in test_chart_dataset_validates_with_3000_sets
self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
AssertionError: False is not true
```